# Python: isna() return different results for a same data sample which is downloaded vs import online using yfinance

Tags: python, pandas

When I run isna() for a downloaded file and for the same data sample from yahoo finance, the number of missing values are different:

```
import yfinance as yf
df2 = yf.download(tickers='BTC-USD', start="2018-06-19", end="2021-06-19")
df_b.isna().sum()

# Compare to:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('BTC-USD.csv')
df.isna().sum()
```

The downloaded file in csv from the same source (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD&.tsrc=fin-srch), same timeframe. Here is my result:

```
df_b.isna().sum()
Open         0
High         0
Low          0
Close        0
Adj Close    0
Volume       0
dtype: int64


df.isna().sum()
Date         0
Open         4
High         4
Low          4
Close        4
Adj Close    4
Volume       4
dtype: int64
```

I don't know where I make my mistake. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is start and end dates are the same for the import file?

Comment: yes, the same, I check it carefully

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for debugging this may be to check if the two dataframes are equal. You can use 'df.equals()' for this.
Or eves start from simply comparing lengths of both dataframes by
'print(df.shape[0] == df_b.shape[0])'